# Check image quality while cropping the image in FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, dart, cross-platform

I am working on an app where the user will be allowed to zoom in and out of a given image.What I want to do is indicate a quality meter to tell the user if the image quality is being reduced every-time the user tries to zoom in / out (crop the image). So that the user knows how much of the quality is dropping on cropping !! I was thinking of using dpi as the metrics to indicate the quality but have not found out any way to get dpi of an image using flutter. Also for the cropping tool I am using the package crop_your_image.

[https://pub.dev/packages/crop_your_image](https://stackoverflow.com)